# iOS: How to build a table from a JSON Query?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, ios

I got a JSON response with a lot of data.

(e.g.: Private Messages).

How to display them into a table?

I mean in C#.net I normaly would have a class (PM) with a lot of Properties (sender, reciever, subject, text) and make a database-query (here JSON) and fill it in a list of my class (List pmList = new pmLIst();).

How to do it in Objective C for iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [SBJson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/). The [TweetStream example project](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/tree/master/Examples/TweetStream/TweetStream) shows how to fetch data over an HTTP connection and parse it. If the data contains a list of objects you'll find those in an NSArray in your parsed data; at that point it's simply a matter of using a [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [restkit](http://restkit.org/). It's a nice framework for parsing JSON and putting it into the right structure. The examples provided there should get you started.